# How to deploy contract at same address across networks?

Tags: solidity

How do you deploy a contract at the same address across multiple networks?

Example Uniswap:

> UniswapV2Factory is deployed at 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f on the Ethereum mainnet, and the Ropsten, Rinkeby, Görli, and Kovan testnets.

Comment: the trick is to make it public once you have all of them deployed successfuly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The contract address is dependent on the address of the deployer and the nonce, so you should just use one account with the same nonce (newly created, for example) on each network and do not make any other transactions other than the deployment.

Comment: yep, any "out of gas" error will screw all the setup on all the networks